# Easiest option to have non-generic ILogger to my aspnet core application

Tags: asp.net-core

According to this documentation, aspnet core 2 (and up) allows an only generic version of `ILogger<Class>`

Is there an easy (least amount of code) option to have non-generic ILogger (like what we had in core 1)  to my aspnet core application?

Comment: You can always create a logger by `LoggerFactory`. e.g. : invoke `var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger("abc");`

Comment: Why do you need this? You can still type your member as `ILogger`; you just have to inject as `ILogger<T>` (i.e. the construct param has to be the generic version, but the actual field you persist it to in the class doesn't have to be). Then, the generic param should just be the class it's injected into, so if you're injecting into `Foo`, you'd use `ILogger<Foo>`. Not really a big deal.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, at the minimum, this question improves my knowledge. I I like to underestand what is behind the Logging and how it works.

Comment: `ILogger` is just a facade. `ILogger<T>` is an `ILogger` that is scoped to a particular type. In the actual concrete log provider, this will generally be a prefix or something to show the context of where the logs are generating. For example, by default you'll see console logs prefixed with `Namespace.To.Type: Something logged here`.